# Critical points of function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

In Manfredo do Carmo's "Differential Geometry of curves and surfaces" a critical point is defined as the point at which the differential is not surjective, and then it goes on to say that this is true only if partial derivatives of the function $f_x$, $f_y$, $f_z$  vanish at the critical point.

I don't get how these $2$ conditions are equivalent.

Comment: The differential at a point is a linear map from a 3-dimensional vector field to a 1-dimensional vector field. The only way for it to not be surjective is if it maps everything to $0$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Oh yes, that explains it. Thanks!